# Windows Azure Multi-Factor Authentication Server and SharePoint 2013

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, azure, sharepoint-2013

What I've got is a SharePoint farm on Azure, IaaS and I have installed the new Multi-Factor Authentication Server for Azure.

It actually works correctly with a normal IIS site, but if you toggle the server to work with a SharePoint web app, subsequent logins to Sharepoint will always generate a 403 error and you won't ever get a call from PhoneFactor.

My question is:  Is there a specific way to configure SharePoint 2013 Authentication to work correctly with the Azure MFA Server?